# How to get DropDownList text from selected value via Linq

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I am quite new to MVC3, and developing a DropDownListFor which i need to get both value and text for display result purpose. Any ideas on this issue? Thanks!

In my controller:

```
       ViewBag.vehicleSizes = totalGreenCalculator.GreenCalculator.getVehicleFuelEfficiency();
```

In my Model:

```
//Datatype: fuelEfficiency = double, vehicleSizes = string
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getVehicleFuelEfficiency()
    {
        var size = new[] {new vehicleSize {fuelEfficiency = 0.0, vehicleSizes = "Choose your     vehicle size"}, 
         //and so on                            
                        };
        return size.Select(a => new SelectListItem() { Text = a.vehicleSizes, Value = a.fuelEfficiency.ToString() });
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GreenCalculator.vehicleList[i].fuelEfficiency, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.vehicleSizes)
```

Comment: please post some relevant code

Answer (score 0):

You can recieve **IDictionary** on controller. Dropdownlist name must match the name of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. It will generate the dropdownlist from the given values. But it won't preselect the default option. That's because in the first argument you have used a complex expression. If you wanted to preselect some item you could do this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.GreenCalculator.vehicleList[i].fuelEfficiency, 
    new SelectList(
        (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.vehicleSizes,
        "Value",
        "Text",
        Model.GreenCalculator.vehicleList[i].fuelEfficiency
    )
)
```